# Normal map baked with seams

Tags: normal-map

Good afternoon, help me figure it out. I have unwrapped my low poly model. When I bake a normal map from high poly to low poly, I see seams on it. However, if I connect the Image Texture node without the map itself, I also see these seams (in the screenshot). They are baked on the normal map. I baked the map in non-color mode. What am I doing wrong?[image: Seams on model]

Comment: Hello could you please share your low-poly + high-poly, also pack your map: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: @moonboots The thing is, when uploading a blend file to Pasteall, I get the error message "Model.blend is not a .blend file". "Model" is the name of my file

Comment: just put the .blend suffix

Comment: @moonboots this doesn't work. 
Other projects load successfully. Including standard cube

Comment: please use another platform like wetransfer, send it to yourself and share the link

Comment: @moonboots Wetransfer link with model
 https://wetransfer.com/downloads/f7d51053b77274b2c144b08e675c0e9f20220304110845/f72e3ad4669dcc3bff5fd28b8e77d51b20220304110845/f3f0f6?utm_campaign=WT_email_tracking&utm_content=general&utm_medium=download_button&utm_source=notify_recipient_email

Comment: it works fine here so I'm not sure why it doesn't for you, maybe make sure that you're using a 32-Bit Float image, also what is your Blender version?

Comment: @moonboots i use steam version, 3.0.1